# How to delete a file from Amazon S3, using Paperclip and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

Just starting with Rails. I have a quick question that uses Paperclip and S3 for a Rails app that I am building, hosted on Heroku.

I've synced everything up so that attachments can be uploaded (both in production and environment) but the only problem is deleting a file from the app/S3. I've done a lot of searching but a lot of the implementations involve checkboxes. I'm also running everything through a Files controller to limit access to admins.

I'm using a simple Project model which has_many attachments.

When I click the delete link, I get an error from S3 saying "Error:
MethodNotAllowed. The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
"

**Here's my view:**

```
<% @project.assets.each do |asset| %>
 <%= link_to File.basename(asset.asset_file_name), asset.asset.url %>
 <small>(<%= number_to_human_size(asset.asset.size) %>)</small>
 <%= link_to '[X]', asset.asset.url , confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this attachment?', method: :destroy %>
```

**Here's my destroy action:**

```
def destroy
   @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
   @asset.destroy
   flash[:notice] = "Attachment has been deleted."
   redirect_to(:back) 
end
```

**The Project model is pretty standard:**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  attr_accessible :asset

  belongs_to :project
  has_attached_file :asset, :storage => :s3, :path => (Rails.root + "files/:id").to_s, :url => "/files/:id"
 end
```

What else am I missing here to get the file removed? Is it something in the model? It all worked well when I wasn't using S3 and deleted from my SQLite or PG database.

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MethodNotAllowed is an HTTP 405, which means you're trying to do something S3 doesn't like. I think the error is with your delete link:

```
<%= link_to '[X]', asset.asset.url , confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this attachment?', method: :destroy %>
```

Basically, you're sending an HTTP destroy to the URL of the file on S3, which should actually go to your Asset controller, and be a `:delete`.

Try:

```
<%= link_to '[X]', asset, confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this attachment?', method: :delete %>
```

In your controller you should then handle deleting the asset:

```
def destroy
   @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
   @asset.destroy
   flash[:notice] = "Attachment has been deleted."
   redirect_to(:back) 
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I understand the reasoning behind this but when I implement it, I get a "Routing Error - No route matches [DELETE] "/assets". Is this because I am doing things through a File controller? A rake routes shows that "DELETE /files/:id(.:format)         files#destroy". But how would I put this into the above link_to? Thank you and so close!

Comment: What's in your routes file?

Comment: You should have something like `resources :assets`.